# PHP MySQL UPDATE causing error

Tags: php, mysql

I was having a look around but I did not seem to find the right answer to this problem I am having. Whenever I run this UPDATE MySQL script, it calls the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Email='contact@example.com', Phone='123456780', Address='16 Remote Street',' at line 1
```

Here is the code I am using to get this error.

```
<?php 
include ('cfg_prop.php');
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$secondemail = $_POST['secondary'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$city = $_POST['city'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET Firstname='$firstname', Lastname='$lastname', Email='$email', Secondary Email='$secondemail', Phone='$phone', Address='$address', Country='$country', Postcode='$postcode', Company='$company', City='$city' WHERE Username='$userss'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

If anyone could help me, I would be really happy and grateful as I just can't seem to get over this. Thanks in advance for the help.

- Alter Arch

Comment: Thank's everyone for your help. It worked. I really appreciate it guys!

Comment: `When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.` http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @hsz Ok. I will do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all - you have to escape data from `$_POST` superglobal because of easy `SQL Injection` attack.

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Next thing you canno use `Secondary Email` because there is whitespace that causes an error.

You have to change colmun's name to `Secondary_Email`.

Or just use

```
`Secondary Email`
```

instead (but do not do this - columns should not have whitespaces in their names).

Comment: Thank's for the security tip!

Answer (score 1):

```
Secondary Email
```

Column has a space in it's name; you should use backtick symbol :

> `

So:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET Firstname='$firstname', Lastname='$lastname', Email='$email', `Secondary Email`='$secondemail', Phone='$phone', Address='$address', Country='$country', Postcode='$postcode', Company='$company', City='$city' WHERE Username='$userss'";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the fastest reply so I am voting your's up. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE users SET 
    Firstname='$firstname', 
    Lastname='$lastname', 
    Email='$email', 
    `Secondary Email`='$secondemail', 
    Phone='$phone', 
    Address='$address', 
    Country='$country', 
    Postcode='$postcode', 
    Company='$company', 
    City='$city' 
WHERE Username='$userss'
```

`Secondary Email` must be enclosed in backticks because contains a whitespace.
Remember to sanitize user input to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to keep it all in one line though just so it is compact.

Comment: @DarayusNanavati: you can keep it in one line. My solutions is just more readable, but you can strip newlines away!!

Answer (score 0):

Escape the field `Secondary Email`

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET Firstname='$firstname', Lastname='$lastname', Email='$email', `Secondary Email`='$secondemail', Phone='$phone', Address='$address', Country='$country', Postcode='$postcode', Company='$company', City='$city' WHERE Username='$userss'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `Firstname`='$firstname', `Lastname`='$lastname', `Email`='$email', `Secondary Email`='$secondemail', `Phone`='$phone', `Address`='$address', `Country`='$country', `Postcode`='$postcode', `Company`='$company', `City`='$city' WHERE `Username`='$userss'";
```

but this method of writing a query is highly recommended by SQL injection!

Comment: Wasn't entirely sure if you were being sarcastic on the SQL injection bit but I am looking into mysql_real_escape_string now

Comment: good! Always use the function mysql_real_escape_string() when you take data via post!